# SSH strange usage text

Tags: ssh

I can't understand ssh usage text:

```
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
       [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
       [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
       [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
       [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
       [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
       [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command [argument ...]]
```

What does `[-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy]` string mean?

Comment: Related [How to read command example syntax in synopsis sections of MAN pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650236/how-to-read-command-example-syntax-in-synopsis-sections-of-man-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `[-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy]` is a list of options that can be used with the `ssh` command.

Meaning of each option you can obtain by running

```
man ssh
```